# Nonce verification failed ERP attendence

Tags: php, erp, nonce

I am using wp erp and wp erp pro. I upload a addon of wp erp which is erp attendence. After activating the erp attendence I am unable to access my admin dashboard it is saying none verification failed. I have also tried clearing the cache but still it is saying nonce verification failed. Is there any way to disable nonce verification for this particular plugin or any other solution.I have tried changing the PHP version but notthing seems to be working.

Comment: rename the plugin directory (wp-contents/plugins/xxxxx) so as to disable it and see the effect

Comment: After disabling the plugin everything works fine. But I have to use this plugin because there no aternative plugins which I can use. I really need this plugin that's why I can't remove it from my website.

Comment: Now you get back the admin dashboard . The next step is to double-check the documentation of this plugin and see what you may have missed. And if necessary, delete the plugin and re-install it carefully.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ejvhltaRTgCJ92yEGfpKGzuDWJCorAsh/view?usp=sharing

This is the readme file which was in the plugin.
Could you please help me to solve this issue

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gujWSN6Qfxf-ucXmlRBdOiRUSxbNtZiW/view?usp=sharing

This is plugin which I want to use

Answer (score 0):

how are you? I recently experienced the same problem and verified that this error occurs because you are trying to install a set of extensions incompatible with the new WP ERP 1.11.1 license. To solve the problem you should download directly from git the **WP ERP version 1.10.5** and manually install it directly in the root directory of your site, where the plugins are in your Wordpress (public_html/content-pluguins). Extract in the same folder the extensions you downloaded from this plugin and also **WP ERP Pro 1.26**. If you follow exactly this way it will work.

WP ERP git site: https://github.com/wp-erp/wp-erp/releases

Good luck!

Comment: I am fine buddy. Thanks for the help. I have fixed it already by changing some codes in wp erp 1.11.1  plugin. But now the problem is that I installed an addon of wp erp but it is not showing in addons section of wp erp that I have installed that addon and because of that I am unable to activate it and use that addon as it is not showing that it is installed.